# angular-ui-mask doesn't mask as expected in the text box

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I am using angular for my web-application and trying to use angular-ui-mask (https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask) to mask the input to prevent someone from even typing anything but numbers in the text box. I've tried everything the doc suggested but I just cannot put it to use. Here is my textbox code snippet.

```
<div class="form-group"><label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Memo</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ui-mask="99-999-9999" ng-model="vm.textField">
  </div>
</div>
```

Not sure if I am missing something or need to add something in my controller. Any clue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you forgot to load the script files...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-ui-mask/dist/mask.js"></script>
```

...or add the module to your dependencies?

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ui.mask', ...])
```

**Edit**: put together a minimal working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/phpu5YRrwPjf5Wv7aASa).

Comment: nope. I did add it. We use bower for the dependencies and shoudn't require this to be included specifically. I see that these are from their github doc and I've tried that approach. But all other libraries we use, we don't need to include it this way.

Comment: Actually, no, you are right, This was indeed missing. Awarded the bounty to you. I should have known this wayy earlier. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I can award the bounty in the next 23 hours but will do it

Comment: Bower will retrieve the dependencies but they still need to be referenced. Anyhow, glad it worked!